# Video started unnecessarily in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I have a `UITableView` & i am playing video in it, at a time 3 cells are visible. on `didSelect` method video start & on `didDeselectRowAt` video removes.

The problems is i didn't play 3rd index cell video but it get started with indexPath 0, As if i start index 1 it also starts index 4 video. Perhaps it's because `dequeueReusableCell`? Any idea?

Source snippet - 
https://gist.github.com/RameshStack/50b1c2880d61c0abc3dedc4d88c71801

Comment: clear all your data in `prepareForReuse` method inside your `UITableViewCell` custom class.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri thanks a TON. Really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear all your data in the `prepareForReuse` method inside your `UITableViewCell` custom class.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    guard let layers = videoView.layer.sublayers else {
        return
    }
    for layer in layers {
        if layer.name == "Video" {
            //(layer as? AVPlayerLayer)?.player?.pause()
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    }
}
```